# Text-based browser in terminal, for Windows, that does not require WSL

Tags: windows, linux, web-browser

Are there any text-based terminal browsers for Windows?
I am using Windows 10 version 10.0.10586 and x64 system.

Please include download links too!

I have heard about W3M browser and I liked it, but it is only available on Linux, so I searched about how to install it on Windows and only answers were with WSL which means Windows Subsystem Linux, but I don't have latest upgrade and anniversary upgrade installed and never will because low space (I am using school laptop which hasn't got much space). Then I searched about text-based browsers but they were only for Unix.

Comment: @Nicolas Raoul Thanks! And Can you answer on my question?